# WP_Query return posts in wrong order

Tags: wp-query

I have a strange WP_Query behavior when using this query arguments:

```
$qargs = array(
        'post_type' => 'any',
        'post_status' => array('publish', 'inherit'),
        'post__in' => $post_ids,
        'lang' => '',
        'posts_per_page' => $atts['limit'],
        'orderby' => 'post__in',
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $qargs );
```

The $post_ids variable contains an array of post IDs:

```
 array (size=9)
      0 => int 30874
      1 => int 30394
      2 => int 30527
      3 => int 30790
      4 => int 30761
      5 => int 30733
      6 => int 30700
      7 => int 30685
      8 => int 30603
```

The first ID (30874) is an attachment type post and when the query returns this post becomes the third in the order and I don't know why.

This is the var_dump of the query object:

```
object(WP_Query)[20311]
  public 'query' => 
    array (size=6)
      'post_type' => string 'any' (length=3)
      'post_status' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'publish' (length=7)
          1 => string 'inherit' (length=7)
      'post__in' => 
        array (size=9)
          0 => int 30874
          1 => int 30394
          2 => int 30527
          3 => int 30790
          4 => int 30761
          5 => int 30733
          6 => int 30700
          7 => int 30685
          8 => int 30603
      'lang' => string '' (length=0)
      'posts_per_page' => string '8' (length=1)
      'orderby' => string 'post__in' (length=8)
  public 'query_vars' => 
    array (size=66)
      'post_type' => string 'any' (length=3)
      'post_status' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'publish' (length=7)
          1 => string 'inherit' (length=7)
      'post__in' => 
        array (size=9)
          0 => int 30874
          1 => int 30394
          2 => int 30527
          3 => int 30790
          4 => int 30761
          5 => int 30733
          6 => int 30700
          7 => int 30685
          8 => int 30603
      'lang' => string '' (length=0)
      'posts_per_page' => int 8
      'orderby' => string 'post__in' (length=8)
      'error' => string '' (length=0)
      'm' => string '' (length=0)
      'p' => int 0
      'post_parent' => string '' (length=0)
      'subpost' => string '' (length=0)
      'subpost_id' => string '' (length=0)
      'attachment' => string '' (length=0)
      'attachment_id' => int 0
      'name' => string '' (length=0)
      'pagename' => string '' (length=0)
      'page_id' => int 0
      'second' => string '' (length=0)
      'minute' => string '' (length=0)
      'hour' => string '' (length=0)
      'day' => int 0
      'monthnum' => int 0
      'year' => int 0
      'w' => int 0
      'category_name' => string '' (length=0)
      'tag' => string '' (length=0)
      'cat' => string '' (length=0)
      'tag_id' => string '' (length=0)
      'author' => string '' (length=0)
      'author_name' => string '' (length=0)
      'feed' => string '' (length=0)
      'tb' => string '' (length=0)
      'paged' => int 0
      'meta_key' => string '' (length=0)
      'meta_value' => string '' (length=0)
      'preview' => string '' (length=0)
      's' => string '' (length=0)
      'sentence' => string '' (length=0)
      'title' => string '' (length=0)
      'fields' => string '' (length=0)
      'menu_order' => string '' (length=0)
      'embed' => string '' (length=0)
      'category__in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'category__not_in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'category__and' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'post__not_in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'post_name__in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'tag__in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'tag__not_in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'tag__and' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'tag_slug__in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'tag_slug__and' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'post_parent__in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'post_parent__not_in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'author__in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'author__not_in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'update_post_term_cache' => boolean true
      'ignore_sticky_posts' => boolean false
      'suppress_filters' => boolean false
      'cache_results' => boolean true
      'lazy_load_term_meta' => boolean true
      'update_post_meta_cache' => boolean true
      'nopaging' => boolean false
      'comments_per_page' => string '50' (length=2)
      'no_found_rows' => boolean false
      'order' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'tax_query' => 
    object(WP_Tax_Query)[20312]
      public 'queries' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      public 'relation' => string 'AND' (length=3)
      protected 'table_aliases' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      public 'queried_terms' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      public 'primary_table' => string 'wp_posts' (length=9)
      public 'primary_id_column' => string 'ID' (length=2)
  public 'meta_query' => 
    object(WP_Meta_Query)[20313]
      public 'queries' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      public 'relation' => null
      public 'meta_table' => null
      public 'meta_id_column' => null
      public 'primary_table' => null
      public 'primary_id_column' => null
      protected 'table_aliases' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'clauses' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'has_or_relation' => boolean false
  public 'date_query' => boolean false
  public 'queried_object' => *uninitialized*
  public 'queried_object_id' => *uninitialized*
  public 'request' => string 'SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.ID IN (30874,30394,30527,30790,30761,30733,30700,30685,30603) AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment', 'staff', 'event', 'publikacio', 'programs') AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'inherit'))  ORDER BY FIELD(wp_posts.ID,30874,30394,30527,30790,30761,30733,30700,30685,30603) LIMIT 0, 8' (length=419)
  public 'posts' => 
    array (size=8)
      0 => 
        object(WP_Post)[20912]
          public 'ID' => int 30394          
          ...
      1 => 
        object(WP_Post)[20941]
          public 'ID' => int 30527
         ...
      2 => 
        object(WP_Post)[20909]
          public 'ID' => int 30874
          ...
      3 => 
        object(WP_Post)[20942]
          public 'ID' => int 30790
          ...
      4 => 
        object(WP_Post)[20943]
          public 'ID' => int 30761
          ...
      5 => 
        object(WP_Post)[20944]
          public 'ID' => int 30733
          ...
      6 => 
        object(WP_Post)[20945]
          public 'ID' => int 30700
          ...
      7 => 
        object(WP_Post)[20946]
          public 'ID' => int 30685
          ...
  public 'post_count' => int 8
  public 'current_post' => int -1
  public 'in_the_loop' => boolean false
  public 'post' => 
    object(WP_Post)[20912]
      public 'ID' => int 30394
      ...
  public 'comments' => *uninitialized*
  public 'comment_count' => int 0
  public 'current_comment' => int -1
  public 'comment' => *uninitialized*
  public 'found_posts' => int 9
  public 'max_num_pages' => float 2
  public 'max_num_comment_pages' => int 0
  public 'is_single' => boolean false
  public 'is_preview' => boolean false
  public 'is_page' => boolean false
  public 'is_archive' => boolean false
  public 'is_date' => boolean false
  public 'is_year' => boolean false
  public 'is_month' => boolean false
  public 'is_day' => boolean false
  public 'is_time' => boolean false
  public 'is_author' => boolean false
  public 'is_category' => boolean false
  public 'is_tag' => boolean false
  public 'is_tax' => boolean false
  public 'is_search' => boolean false
  public 'is_feed' => boolean false
  public 'is_comment_feed' => boolean false
  public 'is_trackback' => boolean false
  public 'is_home' => boolean true
  public 'is_privacy_policy' => boolean false
  public 'is_404' => boolean false
  public 'is_embed' => boolean false
  public 'is_paged' => boolean false
  public 'is_admin' => boolean false
  public 'is_attachment' => boolean false
  public 'is_singular' => boolean false
  public 'is_robots' => boolean false
  public 'is_favicon' => boolean false
  public 'is_posts_page' => boolean false
  public 'is_post_type_archive' => boolean false
  private 'query_vars_hash' => ***
  private 'query_vars_changed' => boolean true
  public 'thumbnails_cached' => boolean false
  private 'stopwords' => null
  private 'compat_fields' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'query_vars_hash' (length=15)
      1 => string 'query_vars_changed' (length=18)
  private 'compat_methods' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'init_query_flags' (length=16)
      1 => string 'parse_tax_query' (length=15)
```

As you see in the results (WP_Query->posts) the 30874 becomes the third. Even the SQL query gives back the right order if I try it in phpMyAdmin.

I need to preserve the post__in order.

I don't understand, please help.

Comment: Do you maybe have sticky posts? you can use `ignore_sticky_posts` for that

Comment: You are right! Somehow I forget about this argument! Thank you very much!